# How to print first side/part of a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

consider this regular python dictionary:

```
Norm_Dict = {
    "x" : "y"
    "m" : "n"
}
```

and so on

My question is how to print the first part of the dictionary (how to print the "x" or the "m")

it is simple to print the secondary statement using formating such as:

```
print Norm_Dict["x"]
```

or so such
but how do you print the other value?

Comment: Uh, with `print 'x'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure which element you want to print. In your example, you want to print the value by giving the key (x), but you didn't mention anything about what you want to print.

Anyway, you can find all keys by the iterator of the dictionary.

```
for key in Norm_Dict:
  print (key)
```

or if you want to 'get' key-value pair at the same time, use

```
for (key, value) in Norm_Dict.items():
  print ('%r: %r' % (key, value))
```

And remember that keys are unique, but values are not. So basically there are no direct ways to use a value to find corresponding keys since this is not what dict is expected to be used. If you need such functions, you have to travel all the dict and record the matching keys by yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it one-shot or in a for loop. Avoid the for loop unless necessary -

**Input**

```
Norm_Dict = {
    "x" : "y",
    "m" : "n"
}
```

**Method 1 without for**

```
print Norm_Dict.keys() # returns a list of the keys (first side as you called it)
```

**Method 2 with for**

```
for x in Norm_Dict:
    print x
```

Comment: this prints  a list of keys or all of the possibilities on the "first side". rather I was wondering if there was a way to specifically print a value on the "first side".

Comment: @callum_wostershire - Yes. What exactly are you looking for? It's not at all clear from your question, thus the extensive guesswork in the current answers.

Comment: I am coding a french dictionary. essentially what I want my code to do is to have a user input a word.  the program would then search through all the possibilities in my dictionary and if the word corresponded to a key in my dictionary, it would print the translation or the "second side",  i was wondering if there was any way I could do this in an opposite fashion - and have my dictionary iterate through the definitions (or in my case french words) and produce a word from the "first side"

Comment: @callum_wostershire - You are already doing that with `Norm_Dict['x']`. I don't understand what sort of answer you're looking for.

Comment: I am sorry if I am unclear, I am just starting with Python and its terminology

Answer (score 0):

For Python 3

```
for key in dict: 
    print(key)
```

is enough.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to print all the keys?  You can do this:

```
Norm_Dict = { "x" : "y", "m" : "n"}

for key in Norm_Dict:
   print ("key: %s , value: %s" % (key, Norm_Dict[key]) )
```